# jQuery bind unbind animation

Tags: jquery, animation, unbind

I made this piece of code,i'm trying to animate a block of text/div back and forward,
but why this works only the first time for the "placeRight" function?
Is there something wrong with the `right : "+=750"` attribute?

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
   $("#text").click(placeRight);
});   

    var placeRight = function() {     
      $("#text").animate( { right :  "+=750" }, 1300); 
      $("#text").unbind("click"); 
      $("#text").click(placeLeft);
    }

    var placeLeft = function() {     
      $("#text").animate( { left :  "+=750" }, 1300); 
      $("#text").unbind("click");
      $("#text").click(placeRight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you have double time `$("#text").animate( { left :  "+=750" }, 1300);`
so you're trying to place it always to +750px position

change it like this

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
   $("#text").click(placeRight);
});   

var placeRight = function() {     
  $("#text").animate( { right :  "+=750" }, 1300);
  $("#text").unbind("click"); 
  $("#text").click(placeLeft);
}

var placeLeft = function() {     
  $("#text").animate( { left :  "-=750" }, 1300); //or { right: 0 }
  $("#text").unbind("click");
  $("#text").click(placeRight);
}
```

Comment: `left :  "0"`This doesn't work.But `right : "-=750"` works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with less code. Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkZtD/1/

Comment: How can i trigger an other animation when toggle?

Comment: I've tried,i want to call a function after the animation completes,but the function triggers first! I used `alert("Complete")` as an example.

Comment: Oh, you want to run something when the animation is done? Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kkZtD/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#text").click(function(){
      $(this).animate({ right: "+=750" }, 1300).animate({ left: "0" }, 1300);
   });
});
```

Comment: No, that's not what the OP wants. He wants the `div` to alternately move left/right when you click it. (see demo http://jsfiddle.net/kkZtD/1/)